# Ouput Caching In asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am currently working in a web application, in that I am trying to implement output caching but it’s not working .actually I am using rad controls in my user control .ascx page.
In the user control I am using cascading dropdown, session, cookies, hidden field, java script, ajax etc. 
I am not able to find why output caching not support in my application.
Can you please guide me on this?

Is there any restriction to implement output caching in an application?

Comment: are you using MVC or webforms or so on? How are you trying to implement caching?

Comment: iam using webform only not MVC

Comment: <%@ OutputCache Duration="300" VaryByParam="None" %> this line code using in aspx page directive

Comment: and how did you verify that caching is not working?

Comment: actually I put beakpoint in pageload .aspx.cs and user control page load also .I press F5 every time its page load hitting and DB also

Comment: this is the most foolish thing i am hearing in months. FYI i have taken a screenshot to share the joke. If you are debugging, it will always hit the breakpoint. Caching will work perfectly if you continue without debugging.

Comment: even I created new aspx page and ascx page in separate folder in same solution and using some rad control but it was working output cache